# Is it possible to create ondemand data by opening a file?

Tags: linux

I would like to stream my Desktop with DLNA to my TV.

- With ffmpeg I am already able to save a video of my Desktop in a file:

  > ffmpeg -framerate ntsc -video_size 1360x768 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 -crf 26 -preset fast -f mpegts videofile
- With the uPnP server MediaTomb I would be able to stream my media files with DLNA.

Now I need just some way to combine both programs such that the output of ffmpeg is directly send to my TV.

What I want:

1. A file is chosen via DLNA.
2. MediaTomb tries to open that file.
3. Instead of receiving the content of the file, the ffmpeg command is executed and the output is returned.

Does anyone know, if that is possible in Linux?

Comment: Although FUSE or one of the file systems build with it might support this, I raise that you would have to buffer the video anyway and that would preclude streaming. So why don't you mirror your desktop with a HDMI output and connect that to your TV with a cable?

Comment: I do not want to do that, because the HDMI input of my TV is not easily accessible and because I would like to be able to stream my Desktop contents over my network or over the Internet (here I could use ffserver).

I don't mind, if the stream is not live on the receiving device, so buffering is no issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a permanently-running ffmpeg writing not to a file but to a named pipe, and DLNA reading from that named pipe.

I do not know if that would work, I have not tested it!